# Combining two arrays based on values php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, array-map, array-walk

I was wondering, how it is possible to perform function on each array element based on value.

For example, if I have two arrays:

```
[
  0 =>  'gp', 
  1 =>  'mnp', 
  2 =>  'pl', 
  3 =>  'reg'
]
```

And

```
$translation = [
    'gp' => 'One',
    'mnp' => 'Two',
    'pl' => 'Three',
    'reg' => 'Four',
    'other' => 'Five',
    'fs' => 'Six'
];
```

How can I get

```
    [ 
      0 =>  'One', 
      1 =>  'Two', 
      2 =>  'Three',
      3 =>  'Four'
   ]
```

?

I managed with foreach, but I believe there are some more efficient ways to do that. I tried to play around with `array_walk` and `array_map`, but din't get it. :(

Comment: Tried `array_combine(array_keys($array1), array_values($translation));` ?

Comment: @jitendrapurohit It doest work if there are different  count of elements in arrays.

Comment: Ohh, thought so, just commented without trying. Thanks

Comment: Just posted an alternate as an answer. Hope it works now..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$arr = [
  0 =>  'gp', 
  1 =>  'mnp', 
  2 =>  'pl', 
  3 =>  'reg'
];

$translation = [
    'gp' => 'One',
    'mnp' => 'Two',
    'pl' => 'Three',
    'reg' => 'Four',
    'other' => 'Five',
    'fs' => 'Six'
];

$output = array_map(function($value)use($translation){
  return $translation[$value];
  }, $arr);

print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => One
    [1] => Two
    [2] => Three
    [3] => Four
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$data = array('gp','mnp','pl','reg');
$translation = array( 'gp' => 'One','mnp' => 'Two','pl' => 'Three','reg' => 'Four','other' => 'Five','fs' => 'Six');
$new  = array_flip($data);// chnage key value pair
$newArr = array();
foreach($new as $key=>$value){
    $newArr[]= $translation[$key];  
}

echo "<pre>";print_r($newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine the keys and values of these arrays using array_combine-

```
$sliced_array = array_slice($translation, 0, count(array1));

array_combine(array_keys($array1), array_values($sliced_array));
```

1st param gives the keys of arrays and second print the values. Finally combine it with array_combine.

Answer (score 0):

```
$toto1 = [
  0 =>  'gp', 
  1 =>  'mnp', 
  2 =>  'pl', 
  3 =>  'reg'
];

$toto2 = [
    'gp' => 'One',
    'mnp' => 'Two',
    'pl' => 'Three',
    'reg' => 'Four',
    'other' => 'Five',
    'fs' => 'Six'
];

$result = array_slice(array_merge(array_values($toto2), $toto1), 0, count($toto1));
```